# Is it worth using with RequireJS for AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, requirejs, js-amd

I have heard that AngularJS has its own module loading mechanism under the hood and using RequireJS is not needed, if not inefficient to use. Is this true? Currently I have an Angular project where the index.html file is getting to be quite big. Should I use RequireJS to mitigate that problem or will that hurt performance? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Adding code to solve problem(s) always hurts performance. Performance is related to having very little code that solves the problem in the most efficient way possible. If angular has its own mechanism, then you don't need require.js. However, since your html is getting quite big - it would appear that require.js is a library that is solving one of your problems - handling dependencies. It's not just a module loader, it can tackle many tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Angular modules need to be available at the startup generally for the bootstrap process. However there is a way to lazy load Angular modules: [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad).

This applies for Angular 1.x. While you can load normal JavaScript with RequireJS this won't work for Angular modules.